# ¿Cómo agregar una capa protectora a los anuncios y, deshabilitando los enlaces que no coincidan con nuestro dominio?

Tags: jquery

Para proteger los anuncios, pensé en crear una capa protectora, es decir, un `div` transparente que se active después de que haya dos o tres `clicks` dados por el mismo usuario y, así, evitar más `clicks` del mismo visitante.

Pero, por supuesto, esto no puede ser suficiente, por lo que además de crear una capa, tendría que eliminar todos los enlaces que contiene el `iframe` o los enlaces y `iframe` que tenga mi contenedor `<div class="ads"></div>`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

   $(".ads iframe").load(function() {
      $(".layer-protect").hide();
   });
});
```

```css
.ads {
    position: relative;
}
.layer-protect {
    position: absolute;
}
iframe {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ads">
    <iframe src="https://es.stackoverflow.com/"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="layer-protect">
   <p>Hi! Testing...</p>
</div>
```

Los enlaces dentro de un `iframe` no los puedo modificar, como ya sabrán que es imposible.

La idea es solo permitir que el usuario de click en esos anuncios solamente dos o tres veces, para ello se debe crear un tipo de contador de clicks y almacenarlos en `localStorage` ya que no es recomendable usar `cookie` porque puede sobrecargar de mi servidor.

El almacenamiento en `localStorage` debe ser de manera segura y que dure por un tiempo limitado de 24 o 48 horas, pasado ese tiempo que se eliminen esos datos, es importante que esa función de vencimiento funcione este o no el usuario en línea.

Por el momento tengo el siguiente código jQuery:

```
let i = 0;
$("iframe *").each(function() {
    this.pos = i;
    $(this).on("click", (e) => {
        if (localStorage.getItem("link"+i) == null) {
                localStorage.setItem("link"+i, 1);
        } else {
           let clicks = localStorage.getItem("link"+i);
           if (clicks >= 3) {
               if (typeof e.target.getAttribute("href") == "string" && e.target.getAttribute("href").toLowerCase().search(location.hostname.toString().toLowerCase()) == -1) {
                  e.preventDefault();
               }
           } else {
             localStorage.removeItem("link"+i);
             clicks++;
             localStorage.setItem("link"+i, clicks);
           }
        }
    });
i++;
});
```

Pero no funciona, he probado creando una pagina con la siguiente estructura:

```
<div>
    <a href="https://example.com" target="_black">1</a>
    <a href="https://example.com" target="_black">2</a>
    <a href="https://example.com" target="_black">3</a>
    <a href="https://example.com" target="_black">4</a>
    <a href="https://example.com" target="_black">5</a>
    <a href="https://example.com" target="_black">6</a>
    <a href="https://example.com" target="_black">7</a>
    <a href="https://example.com" target="_black">8</a>
</div>
```

Y, lo he envuelto/llamado en un `iframe` dando más de 4 veces click en dichos enlaces, pero no se han eliminado ni deshabilitados.

¿Cómo puedo emplear correctamente este problema? me pueden explicar como solucionarlo.

He venido observando algunas referencias:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59573181/adsense-click-tracker-not-working-on-mobile-devices
- https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-make-a-button-disabled-after-3-clicks

Comment: no entiendo lo que quieres lograr en tu escenario ideal. Evitar que google te penalice porque una misma persona genera mucho click-through-rate? Debiese haber maneras de hacer que un aviso ya pinchado no vuelva a salir...

Comment: @ffflabs Es exactamente eso evitar la penalización, estuve 30 días penalizado, por usuarios malintencionado, estoy tratando de reforzar este tema, por ahora ya lo he realizado con PHP, dandole una capa protectora si existen más de 5 visitas por `IP` recordemos que las `IP` no suelen ser únicas y pueden ser usadas por otros usuarios, por eso no aplicó otra función de eliminar anuncios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar un poco de ingenio para lograr un contador de clics sobre los iframes. Incluso si estos están protegidos por restricciones de CORS ( otros orígenes diferentes a tu dominio).

Esto es gracias a que, incluso para accesos de origen cruzados, el navegador necesita una mínima comunicación entre ventanas o marcos.

Manteniendo el foco sobre nuestra ventana principal, podemos capturar cuando perdemos el foco de ella ( a favor del iframe donde el usuario realizó el clic ) y evaluar si el ultimo elemento activo en nuestro sitio fue el iframe que buscamos.

En este momento es importante devolver nuevamente el foco a la ventana principal ( invisible al usuario ) para poder detectar varios clics seguidos.

Te dejo un poco desarrollada la teoría.
Si tienes alguna duda para implementarlo no dudes en consultar.

**Actualización 21/01/2021, persistencia en localStorage**

Versión con persistencia.
Por motivos de restricción de uso de localstorage en stackoverflow. Adjunto ejemplo en *jsfiddle*:

```
const adsProtector = {
  limit : 3,
  current : 0,
  expiration : 60,
  query : '.ads > iframe',
  init : function(){
    const $ = (...args) => document.querySelectorAll(...args);
    let self = this;

    // Persistencia
    let adsProtectorSession = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('adsProtectorSession'));
    adsProtectorSession = (adsProtectorSession.timestamp) ? adsProtectorSession : self._sessionObj();
    self.current = adsProtectorSession.current;

    window.focus();
    self.$frames = $('.ads > iframe');
    self.$frames.forEach(($frame)=>{
      window.addEventListener('blur', () => {
        if(document.activeElement === $frame) {

          // Persistencia
          if((Date.now() / 1000 | 0) > adsProtectorSession.timestamp + self.expiration) {
            adsProtectorSession = self._sessionObj();
            self.current = adsProtectorSession.current;
          }
          adsProtectorSession.current = ++self.current;
          localStorage.setItem('adsProtectorSession',JSON.stringify(adsProtectorSession));

          console.log(`[click detected] ${self.current}`);
          setTimeout(window.focus,1);
          if( self.current >= self.limit ) self.protect();
        }
      });
    });
    },
  protect : function(){
    // Autor: https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/95211/dperezv-com
    console.log(`[Protegido] Sustituye por tu protección. Autor: https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/95211/dperezv-com`);
  },
  _sessionObj : () => ({timestamp :  Date.now() / 1000 | 0, current : 0}),
};

adsProtector.init();
```

[jsfiddle.net/qsaw23co/](https://jsfiddle.net/qsaw23co/)

Expiration está definido en segundos.

**Versión anterior, sin persistencia**

```js
const adsProtector = {
  limit : 3,
  current : 0,
  query : '.ads > iframe',
  init : function(){
    const $ = (...args) => document.querySelectorAll(...args);
    let self = this;
    window.focus();
    self.$frames = $('.ads > iframe');
    self.$frames.forEach(($frame)=>{
      window.addEventListener('blur', () => {
        if(document.activeElement === $frame) {
          self.current++;
          console.log(`[click detected] ${self.current}`);
          setTimeout(window.focus,1);
          if( self.current >= self.limit ) self.protect();
        }
      });
    });
    },
  protect : function(){
    // Autor: https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/95211/dperezv-com
    console.log(`[Protegido] Sustituye por tu protección. Autor: https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/95211/dperezv-com`);
  }
};

adsProtector.init();
```

```html
<div class="ads">
  <iframe class="iframe" src="https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Portada" style="height:100px;width:100%"></iframe>
</div>

<div class="ads">
  <iframe class="iframe" src="https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Portada" style="height:100px;width:100%"></iframe>
</div>

<div class="ads">
  <iframe class="iframe" src="https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Portada" style="height:100px;width:100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: La respuesta es buenísima, el problema es que solo funciona al cargar la página, si recargamos la página el contador se reestablece, te doy +1 de todas maneras

Comment: Gracias por la valoración. No almacena el contador actual ni bloquea el iframe. Pero en mi opinión resuelve el principal problema que nos encontramos al buscar implementar este tipo de solución. Mañana actualizo la respuesta para almacenar como pide el autor original en el cliente el contador de interacciones.

Comment: Actualizado con persistencia el localStorage

Comment: @dperezv.com Perfecto, funciona bien, el tiempo de segundos se cambia aquí `setTimeout(window.focus,1);` ¿verdad?

Comment: @dperezv.com Va bien todo, he probado agregando funciones en la parte de la protección, he cambiado el valor de `1` por `90000` como lo más exagerado, pero... al recargar no funciona, entonces no se esta guardando los datos temporalmente por los minutos.

Comment: @J. Mick El limite en segundos es la propiedad 'expiration' (caducidad) y se expresa en segundos. setTimeout encapsula el retorno del foco, es para obligar al navegador a terminar la propagación antes de devolver al elemento activo a la ventana principal. Siempre debe ser el valor más pequeño posible. En este caso debe quedar como 1. Aumenta 'expiration' de 60 ( 1 min ) al tiempo que quieras mantener el contador.

Answer (score 3):

**(Respuesta reformada)**

---

## 1. Mismo origen

Si tienes un `<iframe>` que tiene el mismo origen que tu dominio, no hay problema, puedes hacer algo simple como:

```javascript
iframe.contentWindow.document
```

De esta manera obtenemos la ventana contenida en el `<iframe>`

#### 1.1 - Obteniendo los links

Podemos hacer simplemente un `querySelectorAll`, de manera que obtendremos los `<a>` del documento del `<iframe>`

```javascript
iframe.contentWindow.document.querySelectorAll("a");
```

Una vez hemos obtenido todos los links, podemos hacer simplemente un `display: none`

```
iframe.contentWindow.document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(el => {
    el.style.display = "none";
});;
```

#### 1.2 - Integración con localStorage

Puedes añadir un *eventListener* a la ventana, de manera que definiremos una función y al cargar la ventana la llamaremos, esta obtendrá todos los links del `<iframe>`, añadiremos un índice único a cada link, de manera que podremos reconocer cada uno en `localStorage`, añadiremos un *eventListener* a cada link, al dar click, se comprobará si el número de clicks es mayor o igual al que definimos en la constante *max*, de ser mayor o igual, haremos un *preventDefault* de manera que ya no redireccionará

```javascript
const cargarLinksStorage = () => {
  const max = 1; // Número máximo de clicks por link
  let iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");
  let elmnt = iframe.contentWindow.document.querySelectorAll("A");
  for(i = 0;i<elmnt.length;i++) {
    if (localStorage.getItem("link"+i) == null){localStorage.setItem("link"+i, "0")}
    elmnt[i].linkPos = i;
    elmnt[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        if (localStorage.getItem("link"+this.linkPos) >= max){
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem("link"+this.linkPos, parseInt(localStorage.getItem("link"+this.linkPos))+1)
        }
    }); }
}

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    cargarLinksStorage();
});
```

#### 1.3 - Fecha de caducidad

Podemos guardar el último día en el mes (De 1 a 30 / De 1 a 31)

De manera que obtendremos el día de hoy en un mes (De la misma manera: 1 - 30 / 1 - 31) Y lo compararemos con la fecha almacenada en *localStorage*, restaremos ambas fechas, el resultado, matemáticamente:

- Dará un número positivo si el plazo es de 48 horas y no se ha vencido
- Dará un número negativo si el plazo es de 48 horas y se ha vencido
- Dará un número positivo empezando a contar desde 1 si el plazo es de 24 horas y no ha vencido
- Dará un número negativo empezando a contar desde 0 si el plazo es de 24 horas y ha vencido

De forma que tenemos el siguiente código:

```javascript
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    cargarLinksStorage();
    let archive = {}, // Notice change here
    keys = Object.keys(localStorage),
    i = keys.length;
    while ( i-- ) {
        archive[ keys[i] ] = localStorage.getItem( keys[i] );
    }
    Object.entries(archive).forEach(entry => {
        const [key,value] = entry;
        if (key.includes("link")) {
            if (localStorage.getItem("lastDate") !== null && parseInt(localStorage.getItem("lastDate")) - new Date().getDate() < -1) { // 0 para 1 día y -1 para 2 días
                localStorage.setItem(key, 0);
                localStorage.setItem("lastDate", new Date().getDate())
            }
        }
    })
    if (localStorage.getItem("lastDate") == null) {
        localStorage.setItem("lastDate", new Date().getDate())
    }
});
```

> es importante que esa función de vencimiento funcione este o no el usuario en línea.

Esto no se puede hacer, si el usuario no ha cargado la página, no se podrá hacer esto, el usuario tendrá que cargar la página obligatoriamente para que los scripts se ejecuten

---

## 2. Diferentes orígenes

Cuando trabajamos con `<iframe>` de distintos orígenes, no será posible acceder al DOM de este, debido a motivos de seguridad, si intentamos hacer un `contentWindow.document`, te dará el siguiente error

```
Access to cross-origin frame has been blocked due to CORS Policy
```

Para solucionar esto, simplemente podemos crear un `<div>` invisible y hacer que se muestre si el contador de click ha excedido los 3 clicks

```javascript
let i = 0;
const max = 2; // Número máximo de click por cada anuncio
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  document.querySelectorAll(".ads").forEach(el => {
    if (parseInt(localStorage.getItem("ad"+i)) >= max) {
      el.innerHTML = `<div class="invDiv"></div>${el.innerHTML}`;
    }
    el.addEventListener("click", () => {
       if (localStorage.getItem("ad"+i) == null) {
          localStorage.setItem("ad"+i, "0");
       } else {
          localStorage.setItem("ad"+i, parseInt(localStorage.getItem("ad"+i))+1)
       }
    });
    i++;
  });
});
```

Además, aplica los siguientes estilos, para que el `<div>` invisible se pueda superponer al `<iframe>` y este no se pueda clickear

```css
/* Estilos necesarios */

.ads {
  position:relative;
}

.invDiv {
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  z-index:20;
}
```

#### 2.1 - Demostración

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  document.querySelectorAll(".ads").forEach(el => {
    el.innerHTML = `<div class="invDiv"></div>${el.innerHTML}`;
  });
});
```

```css
/* Estilos no necesarios con iFrame */

.iframe {
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  border:2px solid red;
}

.iframe > a {
  font-size:6rem;
}

/* END Estilos no necesarios /*

/* Estilos necesarios */

.ads {
  position:relative;
}

.invDiv {
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  z-index:20;
}
```

```html
<div class="ads">
  <div class="iframe"><a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com/">SOes</a></div>
</div>

<!-- Vamos a simular que el div de clase "iframe" es tu iframe -->
```

Como podrás ver, ya no se puede hacer click al enlace, Añadimos, usando javascript, un `<div>` al cargarse la ventana

#### 2.2 - Fecha de caducidad

El método también es similar

```javascript
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    let archive = {}, // Notice change here
    keys = Object.keys(localStorage),
    i = keys.length;
    while ( i-- ) {
        archive[ keys[i] ] = localStorage.getItem( keys[i] );
    }
    Object.entries(archive).forEach(entry => {
        const [key,value] = entry;
        if (key.includes("ad")) {
            if (localStorage.getItem("lastDate") !== null && parseInt(localStorage.getItem("lastDate")) - new Date().getDate() < -1) { // 0 para 1 día y -1 para 2 días
                localStorage.setItem(key, 0);
                localStorage.setItem("lastDate", new Date().getDate())
            }
        }
    })
    if (localStorage.getItem("lastDate") == null) {
        localStorage.setItem("lastDate", new Date().getDate())
    }
});
```

Comment: Hola, existen ejemplos interesantes unos que pueden funcionar perfectamente cuando se trata de proteger contenido o información propia, la cuestión sobre los anuncios de Google Adsense por ejemplo este proveedor crea, genera un iframe, realmente creí que se podría contar los click cada vez que se de click en el algo dentro de ese iframe, incluso aunque no sea el enlace, pero parece no ser así, no parece funcionar, he probado el siguiente código, he dado click en varias ocasiones pero no veo algún efecto de que algo cambie aquí la prueba https://jsfiddle.net/sLx8th03/

Comment: otra prueba https://jsfiddle.net/sLx8th03/2/ sin efecto, ¿entonces no es posible ir contando los eventos que se hagan en un iframe?

Comment: Sin embargo buscando ejemplos he encontrado lo siguiente: https://jsfiddle.net/uwtq8m1j/ en la consola se puede observar que detecta al momento de dar click en el `iframe` entonces si es posible capturar los elementos dados en un iframe, sin importar su contenido, lo que se busca es poder contar los click que se den al contenedor, en este caso el contenedor del `iframe` en la siguiente fuente se usa algunos ejemplos usando un `:after` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080222/add-click-event-to-iframe lo he probado: https://jsfiddle.net/2mcdLpz1/ no me gusta las ventanas por clic

Comment: Probado https://jsfiddle.net/2mcdLpz1/1/ pero las ventas emergentes no me agradan, te comparto cada una de las pruebas para ver si así podrías darme una alternativa que funcione... En algunos comentarios de esta pregunta observe lo siguiente: *crear `div transparente` encima del `iframe` (use la posición: absoluta). A continuación, puede capturar clics en ese `div`. No olvide pasarlos al `iframe`* por lo que crear una capa trasparente esta sencillo aquí lo he realizado sin problemas: https://jsfiddle.net/gqkp80s6/

Comment: @J.Mick debido a problemas de seguridad, no puedes acceder al contenido de un iFrame que no es de tu dominio, puedes usar la `alternativa`

Comment: No necesito acceder a la información del `iframe` solo capturar el elemento, como si diéramos en clck en un div, en este caso como se dijo los comentarios crear un div transparente y así obtener el evento en todo caso.